# Model fetch() not firing any event

Tags: javascript, events, backbone.js, model, fetch

I've created one backbone model called 'artist' and one backbone view called 'artistView'. I sucessfully fetched the model as I could see it in my Chrome devtools network tab.

However, fetch didn't fire any 'change' event at that moment.
The weird thing is that it fired well a 'change' event when it created the model but not when it fetched this one...

I could use the success callback in the fetch() method but I feel this is not the most proper way to do that. Any idea ?

**Model & View initialization :**

```
var artist = new Artist({id: 3});
var artistView = new ArtistView({model: artist});
```

**I then fetch my model :**

```
artist.fetch();
```

**In my backbone View class, I listen to the 'change' event coming from the model :**

```
var ArtistView = Backbone.View.extend({

    initialize: function() {
        this.model.on("change", this.test());
    },

    test: function() {
        console.log(this.model.get("name"));
    }
});
```

**Edit: "sync" event isn't working either. When I create the model it fires well a 'sync' event but not when the model has been successfully fetched.**

Comment: Listen for the sync event.

Comment: You're right sync would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem came from my event listener. It actually didn't take the context into account.

Here is the solution :

```
this.model.on("sync", this.test, this);
```

And not

```
this.model.on("sync", this.test());
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the "sync" event.

```
  var ArtistView = Backbone.View.extend({

    initialize: function() {
        this.model.on("sync", this.test());

    },

    test: function() {
        console.log(this.model.get("name"));
    }
});
```

Change only fires when an attribute changes.

[Docs](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-catalog).

Edited thx to stephen.

Comment: Just tested and it is unfortunately not working. The test method is called when the model is created but not when it is successfully fetched. Crazy...

Comment: It should come from my event listener as I've just manually triggered a "sync" event and nothing came up.

Comment: Here is the solution : this.model.on("sync", this.test, this); :)